# Are Data Transformations Necessary in Multiple Linear Regression (Lagged Independent Variables) and Time Series Analysis?

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, cross-correlation, lags

I created a regression model on lagged independent variables (monthly data) for the past 4 years.  Essentially, after transforming the data to make it stationary I used the ccf plot in R to determine which lags to incorporate into the analysis.  The plot is below. Upon incorporating lags at months 10 and 11 (strongest correlation), the regression yields an adjusted R2 of less than 40%.  Also, incorporating lags 2 and 5 did not significantly impact the model.

[image]

Two questions:

1. Is the data transformation for stationarity necessary?  I used both the first difference and a log transformation and it did not improve the model based upon the adjusted R2.
2. Also, after selecting the regression equation the confidence interval becomes very wide as you project out past a year.  The goal is to have a better fitting model in order to use the regression equation as a projection method.

Comment: It helps to use time-averages. In this data, it looks like a time averaging window of 5-10 points might yield a useful signal.

Comment: I used the average and it didn’t improve the adjusted R squared. Any other suggestions? I appreciate the feedback. Do we have to make the variables stationary?